# Geting video input through ports in android

Tags: android

I wonder if there is a way to pass video stream through computer(any hardware) to android using ports. Is there a way? What I'm looking for is a way to get video from a port and then manipulate it using openCV or sth else.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to get data from an external input e.g external camera or sth, because there is no host and cellphone to do this. All devices that we can connect to cellphone is keyboard,flash disk,mouse,... with usb on the go(OTG).